# How to splitting values in int serial read values

Tags: serial, serial-data

I get values in serial read using the following code,

```
int32_t bytesSent = 0;

if (mySerial.available()) {
    bytesSent = mySerial.read();
}
```

Output:

`Serial.write(bytesSent);` gives `-1199/1211` value.

I need to split this value into two values. That should separate using "/" point.

Value 1 - `-1199`
Value 2 - `1211`

The following code is used for char type values separate when `numberArray3[20] = "-1199/1211"`

```
    char numberArray3[20];

   int len = strlen(numberArray3);
   int pos = strcspn(numberArray3,"/");

   char First[20];
   char Second[20];
   
   strncpy(Second, numberArray3+pos+1, len);
   strncpy(First, numberArray3, pos);
   Serial.println(First);
   Serial.println(Second);
```